# Data extraction and cleaning | Reading txt file and using grep

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am reading multiple txt files using read.csv2 which saves them in a tibble format.

I want to then extract row number with a certain string 'NASDAQ' and remove all rows above it and another string 'End' and remove all rows below it. Now when I use grep to do so, it always returns 1 as the value even though for, e.g., if my 'NASDAQ' row is row number 3. Also please note that there could be 2 'END' rows and I want to select the first one. An example is given below

I will then combine the remaining rows in one continuous text and save in a data frame.

```
*# A tibble: 12 x 1*
   X1                                                       
   *<chr>*                                                    
 1 "AMERICAN EXPRESS"           
 2 "Date: Aug 13 2020 12:01:33"                             
 3 "NASDAQ"           
 4 "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
 5 "consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt" 
 6 "aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
 7 "laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."     
 8 "Aug/13/2020"                                            
 9 "End"                              
10 "Copyright (c) 2020"                                     
11 "END of story"
12 "\f"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `match` to get the index of position where `'NASDAQ'` and `'End'` are present and paste all the values between them in one string.

```
start <- match('NASDAQ', df$X1)
end <- match('End', df$X1)
text <- paste0(df$X1[start:end], collapse = ' ')
text
```